# ABSMIDDLE works differently on Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have an icon image and text like the following. The code source of everything is:

```
<img src="...." align="absmiddle" /> My Title Here
```

The problem is that the icon is not aligned vertically with the title in Chrome compared to firefox.

[image]

I think the `absmiddle` doesn't work at all! Is there any solution? I don't want to use a table with 2 columns to fix this issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
<img src="img.png" style="margin-bottom:.25em; vertical-align:middle;">
```

Comment: margin-bottom:.25em is unbelievable - never knew about this. It gets the alignment prefect across browsers.

Answer (score 2):

`vertical-align: middle;` may be what you're looking for. I wouldn't necessarily assume WebKit knows from "absmiddle".

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it's the same

Comment: Note that you may have to set it on a containing element, and alex is probably right (which may not adversely affect the layout).

Answer (score 2):

The align attribute of  has been deprecated and is not supported in HTML 4.01 Strict or XHTML 1.0 Strict.

You should use CSS to achieve this effect. You could try the following code:

```
<img src="...." align="absmiddle" style="vertical-align:middle;" /> My Title Here
```

or

```
<img src="...." align="absmiddle" style="vertical-align:50%;" /> My Title Here
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, `vertical-align:middle;` alone was not enough (on IE at least and with a textbox beside).
What works very well is along with `border-style: none;`:

```
<img src="...." style="vertical-align:middle; border-style: none;" />
```