# <h:graphicImage> vertical alignment

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have this image:

```
<h:graphicImage library="images" name="lighton.png" height="22" rendered="#{mController.dothat}" />
```

which I need to be vertical aligned to a field.

Manually adding (e.g. via firebug) **align="absmiddle"** to the produced `<img/>` tag does work. Nevertheless, adding it to the graphicImage tag, does nothing.

Comment: It would be great if you add the JSF/HTML code that surround the `<h:graphicImage>` in order to help you.

Comment: it's surrounded by a "p:commandLink" which is placed correctly aligned

Comment: Looks like a CSS problem. Check proposed solutions http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t156512-css-replacing-img-align-absmiddle.html and http://stackoverflow.com/a/5203632/1065197

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Styling/positioning elements/attributes like `font`, `center`, `align`, `bgcolor`, etc are **deprecated** since HTML 4.01 in 1998. Keep yourself up to date. You are supposed to use CSS for that.

Set the CSS `vertical-align` property to `middle`, either by an inline style (poor practice)

```
<h:graphicImage ... style="vertical-align: middle;" />
```

or by a style class (recommended practice) on the element or perhaps a parent

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />
...
<h:graphicImage ... styleClass="someSensibleClassName" />
```

with in `/resources/css/style.css`

```css
.someSensibleClassName {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```